# Android PHP Mysql get Data by params

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I'm making android app with communication to PHP MySQL
there is PHP files

```
create_order.php
get_all_orders.php
get_order_status.php
```

create_order.php works
get_all_orders.php also
but example in browser I'm typing get_order_status.php?oid=102 it gives me response but it contains an error 
`{"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing get status"}` when  trying it from android by POST method

```
RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();

        String num1 = "1";

        if (num1 != null && !num1.equals("")) {
            String uri = String
                    .format("http://192.168.0.101/android_connect/get_order_status.php?param1=%1$s",
                            num1);

            StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    uri,
                    createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                    createMyReqErrorListener());
            queue.add(myReq);
        }
```

get_order_status.php

```
/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
//require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
//$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data

//echo("post data - ".$_GET['oid']);

if (isset($_GET['oid'])) {
    $pid = $_GET['oid'];

    // get a order from orders table
 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','rootpass','testdb');

 $result = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE oid = $pid")); 
     //echo($result["status"]);
    if (count($result)>0) {
        // check for empty result


            $order = array();
            $order ["status"] = $result["status"];

            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["order"] = array();

            array_push($response["order"], $order);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No order found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
   $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing get status";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query.

Comment: Perhaps you should word your question as a question. It is also unclear which code snippet you included and why.

Answer (score 0):

change `param1` to `oid` in this line (android code)

```
String uri = String.format("http://192.168.0.101/android_connect/get_order_status.php?param1=%1$s",num1);
```

should be like this:

```
String uri = String.format("http://192.168.0.101/android_connect/get_order_status.php?oid=%1$s",num1);
```

as in your PHP file you are reading parameter named `oid`

```
$pid = $_GET['oid'];
```